# Косинус через рекурсию питон

Tags: python, функции, рекурсия

Нужно написать рекурсивную функцию для поиска косинуса по формуле:
`((-1)^n * x^2*n) / (fac(2*n))`.

Функция факториала уже есть:

```py
def fac(n):
    return 1 if (n < 1) else n * fac(n-1)
```

помогите пожалуйста.

Comment: Факториал в Питоне уже есть. В этой задаче факториал не нужен. Формулу вы записали не полностью/криво. Сами попробовали что-нибудь? Добавьте в вопрос вашу попытку.